# Using the value of a directive within a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which takes the value of ng-Category:

```
$app.directive('ngCategory', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            var **categoryItem** = attrs.ngCategory ;       
        }            
    }   
});
```

And I use that returned value direcitve within the controller:

```
$app.controller( 'Pedido', ['$scope', '$http' , function( $scope , $http ) {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'js/menu/menu.json' }).success( function( data ) {
        $scope.posts = data;

        $scope.listItens = [],
        $scope.minValue ;

        ...

        **categoryItem**
    }); 
}]);
```

But I can not, can anyone help?

Comment: that variable is local to the link function in your directive, so you won't be able to use it anywhere else with the way you have it there. Also, you shouldn't name your custom directives starting with "ng". What are you trying to do with this code? Does your controller have anything to do with the directive? Could you put the value on the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local variable of a directive in a controller. In order to make that happen you need to have a variable binded to the directive two-way. One can achieve this using ngModel in the directive something like this:

OPTION I:

```
$app.directive('ngCategory', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,ngModel) { 
            ngModel.$setViewValue = attrs.ngCategory ;       
        }            
    }   
});
```

In Html

```
<button ng-category ng-category ="counter">Click Me</button>
```

OPTION II

Another way is to have the directive like this:

```
$app.directive('ngCategory', function() {
    return {
        scope: { title:'=title' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            scope.title = xyz ;       
        }            
    }   
});
```

For this the html:

```
<button ng-category title ="counter">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: But how do I use inside CONTROLLER?

Comment: You are passing the $scope variable counter to directive. The same can be used in controller

Comment: @Mayrink if you need to get the lowest value of each category you can make use of angular filter instead of directives over here